# Where can one download the pre-release version of ANT 1.8.3?

Tags: java, ant

Ant's current release is 1.8.2, but I found a 1.8.3 readme via google that indicates a bug that I'm interested in was fixed in that version.

Does anyone know how I most easily obtain 1.8.3? They don't seem to make it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either [build it yourself from source](http://ant.apache.org/svn.html) or use the [nightly builds from their CI server](https://builds.apache.org/job/Ant_Nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/distribution/binaries/). Obviously use at your own risk - there's no guarantee the latest code will work, and the binaries are tagged "alpha".

Answer (score 1):

[Subversion snapshot](http://svn-master.apache.org/snapshots/ant/)

Most probably you'll have to build this pre-release yourself from the subversion repository.